# How to ensure XSD Validation of Date and DateTime fields includes timezone

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Is there a way to enforce that a xsd:date or xsd:datetime field includes the timezone in an xml payload?

All validators, eclipse, camel, etc that I have tried accept the fields regardless of whether a timezone is attached or not.

I would like to enforce the requirement that a timezone is always present in the XML.

EDIT:

I was hoping that there was a standardised way of dealing with this situation.

In the end as I am using 1.0 XSD went with the following solution:

```
<xs:simpleType name="dateNoTz">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="dateTimeNoTz">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d(.\d?\d?\d?)"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="dateTimeTz">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d(.\d?\d?\d?)?((\+[01]\d:[0-5]\d)|Z)"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="dateTz">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d((\+[01]\d:[0-6]\d)|Z)"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by adding an [XSD pattern facet](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-pattern) to the simple type. If you add a pattern facet that lexically requires the value to contain timezone information, then each value of this type will be required to satisfy this pattern facet, and thus will have to contain timezone information.

Answer (score 3):

In XSD 1.0, you can only do it by use of a pattern (regular expression).

In XSD 1.1 there is a new facet `explicitTimeZone`.

Comment: good one! i did not know about that useful addition in XSD 1.1.